# Rstudio force Mac to download from iCloud

Tags: r, macos, icloud

My Mac laptop is set up to upload large data files to iCloud, leave a name stub and delete from my local hard drive. This is not necessarily a bad thing. When I go to the directory and click the name stub, the file starts downloading. But when I try to read in one of these files in an R script, Rstudio (and presumably R, although I haven't tried that) just says that the file is missing.

How can I tell RStudio to force the mac to download the file?

Comment: `system(paste("open", file.choose()))` should do what the Finder does when you click on a file.

Comment: What this does is open a window and allow me to click on the download option. But I'd like to have this happen automatically; that is, I read.csv or readRDS the file name and it automatically downloads the file and imports it.

Comment: This is embedded into the OS, so I'm not sure how you would mimic the behaviour of navigating to the file in your directory to trigger the download -- one solution though is to turn off the "Optimize Storage for iCloud Drive" so that files are always stored locally and therefore accessible